# How to change references of a class to another class in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have created a new class out of an old class with different method implementations. Now, I want to update all the references of that old class to this new class. Is there anyway to do this automatically in eclipse?

I can actually do a rename(with update references) to this old class and copy the new code into this but the entire code being in source control makes my life a tougher with this process.

I am just wondering if there is an easy way to do this and have both classes at the end and have the references updated to the new class.

Comment: You mean you refactorred an old class? In eclipse that would make also the reference changes.

Comment: Hi Lukas, I have created a new class without touching the old class.

Answer (score 1):

Using the refactoring functionality should do the trick. Refactor the old class into the new one:

Right click on the class name, Refactor > Rename > Put the new name of the class > Press Enter.

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any existing refactoring that does exactly that, but it's simple enough to:

1. Temporarily rename your new class to something else.
2. Do a refactor/rename of the old class to the new class name.
3. Manually (non-refactor) rename the old class back to its original name.
4. Manually (non-refactor) rename the new class back to its original name.

That way you get the power of the rename refactoring to help you update the references, but in the end, the classes are still the same as they were.

Comment: Hi Ryan.. This is the approach I figured out and followed. But I had to go through a lot of pain because the code is source controlled. So, wondering if there is a simpler approach.

Comment: I don't understand how source control means a lot of pain. If your IDE doesn't take care of it for you, maybe you're using the wrong IDE.

Answer (score 0):

right click your class file select refactor then rename it what ever you want ..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that person asking the question is using something like Perforce or ClearCase where temporarily renaming files is a pain.

The best bet is to do a simple Eclipse global file search and replace. 
Click on Search -> File
and click on the Replace button on the bottom.

[image: Eclipse File-Replace Search]

Comment: I think you understood my problem correctly. But this may not work in my case because there are a lot of other classes and methods which have the old class name as its substring.